# How to create loop cut through an object?

Tags: edit-mode

To make things easier to understand, I have some photos below.

Now, if I create a 4x4 tile, then extrude the outer 12 squares, I get a cup-shaped object.

[image: fig 1]

But if I create a Loop Cut on this object, you can see that it doesn't reach to the inside of the object.

[image: no loop cut o no]

How do I make it so that a loop cut reaches through the entire object?

Thanks for taking the time to read my post!

Comment: That is not possible, In this specific case it might seem trivial, but on more complex shapes how would Blender know where to cut? Use *knife project* instead

Comment: If going into wireframe mode doesn't work, then you can use the knife tool in wireframe view and use it there.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I'm trying to make a 2D, horizontal, level loop cut that reaches through the whole object. Like a plane that cuts through the object. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop cut is always made on one loop of faces.
In your example you have 2 separate loops so it cannot be cut at once with this tool.

What you can do is to make one loopcut for each face loop (inner & outer):
[image]

or use Knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> with <kbd>Z</kbd> (*cut through*) option enabled (the Z key is not captured in the example). Hold Ctrl to make a cuts in the middle of edges or if you want to place it some were else but have it accurate press <kbd>C</kbd> to constrain the direction of the cut to 45 degree steps.

[image]

Comment: This method works fine on the simple model that I made, but I'm not sure if it will work on more complicated models with lots of little chambers and things..? (I actually read about this method, but they put it in the most complicated way possible.. Thanks for making it so easy to understand) Anyways, this seems to work well, so I marked it as the answer.

Comment: I think that if you need to do this too often, you should change your modeling workflow. Also look at Subdivide - if you select all vertical edges here and press W -> Subdivide, you would also get the same result.